# Tag based Parser in PHP refusing to send value to function

Tags: php, parsing

I've got a problem with my preg_replace parser, and I can't figure out what I've done wrong. At the moment, the parser will run through and replace html and run functions as it's supposed to, with one hiccup. The very last function will always be run, regardless of the data that's been submitted from the database. I've been fighting with this for a couple of weeks now, and I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Notice: Undefined index: \1 in ...\pgame.php on line 69
```

Line 69 just refers to the line where a test vs. a value in the session is committed. Now, this code by all accounts should *not be run yet*, but it is being run and sending a notice about the value \1, which it shouldn't be able to have been sent in the first place. Here's the function that's being run:

```
66 function changelike($charac, $val){
67  //check the state of character
68  global $con, $player, $valarr;
69  $test = $_SESSION[$charac];
70  if($test == -1){
71      //if at -1, set to 50
72      $test = 50;
73  }
74  $test += $val;
75  $valarr[0] = 1;
76  $valarr[1] = $test;
77  $valarr[2] = $charac;
78  
79  }
```

And here is the parser, the only place in the script it's being referenced from:

```
function scenerender ($string) {
$playername=$_SESSION['name'];
$search = array(
    '#[[]comp l\=(.*?) t\=(.*?)[]](.*?)[[]/comp[]]#',
    '#[[]lopen[]]#',
    '#[[]lclose[]]#',
    '#[[]nl[]]#',
    '#[[]pn[]]#',
    '#[[]name\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]lmenuopen[]]#',
    '#[[]lmenuclose[]]#',
    '#[[]lperson\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]cperson\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]rperson\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]lobj\=(.*?)[]](.*?)[[]\/lobj[]]#',
    '#[[]img[]](.*?)[[]\/img[]]#',
    '#[[]button\=(.*?)[]](.*?)[[]\/button[]]#',
    '#[[]rspc\ =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]] =[[](.*?)[]][]](.*?)[[]\/rspc[]]#',
    '#[[]wavsound\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]mp3sound\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]oogsound\=(.*?)[]]#',
    '#[[]moodmod\=(.*?) n=(.*?)[]]#'
);
$replace = array(
    '<a href=\'mail.html\' target=\'_blank\'><img src=\'\\3\' style=\'position:absolute;top:\\2;left:\\1\'></a>',
    '<map name=\'doormap\'>',
    '</map>',
    '<br>',
    $playername,
    '<h2 style=\'color: rgb(255, 255, 255);position:absolute;top:285;font-size:165%;\'>\\1</h2>',
    '<img src=\'gui/speechbox.png\' id=\'textfill\'><div id=\'text\'><center style=\'font-size:105%;font-weight:bold;\'>',
    '</center></div>',
    '<img src=\'\\1\' style=\'position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:10px;\'>',
    '<img src=\'\\1\' style=\'position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:101px;\'>',
    '<img src=\'\\1\' style=\'position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:191px;\'>',
    '<area shape=\'polygon\' coords=\'\\2\' onclick=\'loadbyref(\\1)\' href=\'#none\'>',
    '<img src=\'\\1\' usemap=\'\#doormap\'>',
    '<button onclick=\'loadbyref(\\1)\'>\\2</button>',
    randspeach( '\\1', '\\2', '\\3', '\\4', '\\5', '\\6', '\\7', '\\8', '\\9', '\\10'),
    canplaysound('<audio autoplay><source id=\'plc\' src=\'\\1\' type=\'audio/wav\'></audio>'),
    canplaysound('<audio autoplay><source id=\'plc\' src=\'\\1\' type=\'audio/mp3\'></audio>'),
    canplaysound('<audio autoplay><source id=\'plc\' src=\'\\1\' type=\'audio/oog\'></audio>'),
    changelike(' \\1', '\\2')
);
return preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
```

What this should be doing is consulting the session for a value referenced by the variable charac, but even when it's called from it's proper tags it doesn't transfer either value referenced by //1 and //2. Instead, it passes /1.

Am I missing something important? Any help on this matter, or even a nudge in the right direction on how to properly send values and do this would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

I've got it working with preg_replace_callback(). I really wish PHP had some better documentation on it's functions, specifically how it outputs from one function to another.
If anyone can shed some light on the previous error(why it always ran the last item in the array when changelike() was introduced) your help would be much obliged.

Comment: If you want to process replacements like that, look at `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Would Preg_replace_callback allow me to reference the replaced pattern by it's position in the pattern array? If so, I could just manage most of the messy stuff via a switch.

Comment: you're putting `changelike(' \\1', '\\2')` as last element in an array, so it's going to run, right there. Did you mean to put it there as a function to eventually call? Because that's very much not what you're doing right now.

Comment: It's supposed to be called when I pass the tag [moodmod=? n=?] from the string. This previously worked before I added the last tag and the function call changelike(' \\1', '\\2') with just canplaysound('<audio autoplay><source id=\'plc\' src=\'\\1\' type=\'audio/oog\'></audio>'), and works if I take the last entry on both arrays out. I'm still not quite sure what the difference between the functions is, and why it won't run canplaysound() as it's supposed to but is forced to run changelike()

Comment: Sorry - Why it will run canplaysound() only when it's called, as it's supposed to, and has to run changelike(). On a hunch, I moved both calls to the center of the script with the exact same effect - changelike() is run every time, regardless of if it's called. However, if the reference is removed from the array it will not be called, as proper.